# Celery sub tasks on different remote machines

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have two servers where Celery workers are running. Let's call them R1 and R2.

From my other server (say R3), I want to create chained tasks such that **R1.task task** gets created which then creates **R2.task subtask**

But I seriously doubt if this is possible. I have tried

```
# celery_apps.py on R3
from celery import Celery

from application.config import get_application_config

__author__ = 'hussain'

config = get_application_config()

celery_app_r1 = Celery(
    'R1',
    broker=config.CELERY_BROKER_URL_R1
)

celery_app_r2 = Celery(
    'R2',
    broker=config.CELERY_BROKER_URL_R2
)

celery_app_r1.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACKS_LATE='True',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']
)

celery_app_r2.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACKS_LATE='True',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']
)
```

And this is how I am trying to create chained tasks

```
# client.py on R3
from celery import subtask
celery_app_r1.send_task(
    'communication.tasks.send_push_notification',
    (json.dumps(payload), ),
    exchange=config.CELERY_COMMUNICATION_EXCHANGE,
    routing_key=config.CELERY_PN_ROUTING_KEY,
    link=subtask(
        'application.tasks.save_pn_response',
        (device.id, ),
        exchange=config.CELERY_RECRUITMENT_EXCHANGE,
        routing_key=config.CELERY_CALLBACKS_ROUTING_KEY
    )
)
```

There is no way I could even mention celery_app_r2.

How can I run such subtasks on different remote machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 2 apps, 2 brokers or 2 exchanges. The broker is the shared link between your machines for communication and such.

What you need are 2 queues, one for each server and route your tasks accordingly with diffirent routing_keys or straight up enforcing queue name.

**Quick example:**

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('notifications'),
    Queue('callbacks')
)
```

Then launch one worker in each server with:

```
celery worker --app app -Q notifications --loglevel info
celery worker --app app -Q callbacks --loglevel info
```

And send the callback tasks from within the notification:

```
@app.task(queue='notifications')
def notification_task(*args, **kwargs):
    # ... whatever your notification logic is
    callback.s(arg1, arg2).delay()

@app.task(queue='callbacks')
def callback(*args, **kwargs)
    # ...
```

Notice I'm not using `send_task`, but importing the function directly. You do not need `send_task` unless you're calling tasks from a server with a different code base. I.e. if your projects grow and want to separate repositories, etc.

Comment: I definitely need to use `send_task`. As you said, the objective of using `send_task` is the code base are separately put. 1. R3 has just celery client code 2. R1 and R2 have codebase specific to them.

Comment: Now I get it. I guess I got confused thinking I would need two brokers. What I have already done works with one broker and workers on R1 and R2 consuming different queues. I should probably take down my question.

Comment: Calling subtasks from inside another class is explicitly not recommended by celery authors, use chains or groups